# Event handling from inside an Async method

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin.android, zxing

I have an activity in MonoForAndroid that makes use of [Zxing.Net.Mobile](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/) for scanning barcodes on Android. Everything works fine in terms of scanning and returnning results. However, when I try to handle any events on the scanOverlay, I get nullReferenceException. My code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
public async void StartScanSession(ScanSessionEventArgs e)
{
        EnsureLoadingZxingOverlay(e);
        EnsureStartingZxingBarcodeScanner();            
        var zxingOptions = MobileBarcodeScanningOptions.Default;

        var result = await ZxingBarcodeScanner.Scan(zxingOptions);
        HandleScanResult(result, e);
 }

private void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result, ScanSessionEventArgs e)
{
    if (result != null && e.OnFinishCallBack != null)
    {
        var scanResult = new ScanResult { ShouldStopScanning = false, BarcodeText = result.Text, ScanTime = result.Timestamp, BarcodeFormat = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString(), RawBytes = result.RawBytes };
        e.OnFinishCallBack(scanResult);
    }
}

private void EnsureLoadingZxingOverlay(ScanSessionEventArgs e)
{
    if (ZxingOverlay == null)
    {
        ZxingOverlay = LayoutInflater.FromContext(this).Inflate(Resource.Layout.scan_custom_layout, null);
        ScanLayoutFlashButton = ZxingOverlay.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ScanLayoutFlashButton);
        ScanLayoutDoneButton = ZxingOverlay.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.ScanLayoutDoneButton);

        UnhookZxingLayoutButtons();
        ScanLayoutFlashButton.Click += (sender, args) => ZxingBarcodeScanner.ToggleTorch();
        ScanLayoutDoneButton.Click += (sender, args) => HandleDoneButtonOnZxingScanLayout(e);
    }
}
```

All this code above is working fine. However, when I try to handle Done button on the layout, I get the NullReferenceException

```
 private void HandleDoneButtonOnZxingScanLayout(ScanSessionEventArgs e)
 {
       var result = new ScanResult { ShouldStopScanning = true };
       if (e.OnFinishCallBack != null && ZxingBarcodeScanner != null)
       {
           // at this line below, ZxingBarcodeScanner is null, 
           // but I am sure I have initiated before wiring the event
           // I am guessing it is something to do with the context of the async method??
            ZxingBarcodeScanner.Cancel();
            e.OnFinishCallBack(result);
        }
  }
```

Details of the exception below

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at Leopard.Mobile.Screens.QVgaPortrait.MainScreen.HandleDoneButtonOnZxingScanLayout (Leopard.Mobile.Business.Event.ScanSessionEventArgs) [0x0001e] in ...\MainScreen.cs:178
at Leopard.Mobile.Screens.QVgaPortrait.MainScreen/c__DisplayClass8.b__6 (object,System.EventArgs) [0x00000] in ...\MainScreen.cs:156
at Android.Views.View/IOnClickListenerImplementor.OnClick (Android.Views.View) [0x0000d] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/d23a19bf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:1615
at Android.Views.View/IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/d23a19bf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.Views.View.cs:1582
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.49957671-33c0-4b79-8c3b-36f419ebfaaa (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: Please post the exception details, including stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, added the details of the exception above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any problem with the way I had set up the methods and events of the `Zxing` library. Especially after doing the same settings on `MonoTounch` and all worked fine. Thus, I went into the source code to see what does the `scanner.Cancel()` method does internally. I found that it just calls the `Cancel()` `static` method on the `ZxingActivity`, so I did that from my code and all seemed to work fine. 
This is probably not the most elegant solution, and I have reported an issue on the `Zxing.Net.Mobile` repo on github ([here](https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/issues/84)), but for now this works, and I hope it could help someone else too. I also have a full post detailing my experience with using this library on `MonoDroid` in case anybody needs it [here](http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/barcode-scanning-on-monoforandroid/).

so the fix was replacing this line (from the above code):

```
ZxingBarcodeScanner.Cancel();
```

with this line:

```
ZxingActivity.RequestCancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment due to lack of reputation so posting here.

We had a similar issue with another third party application going out of scope.  Have you done any level of thread safety checking? Maybe your *ZxingBarcodeScanner* can only be accessed via the thread which created it, i.e. the thread which called "StartScanSession".